# Как управлять сокетами через Socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, websocket, socket.io

Мне нужно держать страницы на постоянном соединении с сервером. Я наткнулся на `Socket.io`. Я раньше не был знаком не с `Node.js`, не с `Socket.io`. Сделал на стороне сервера следующее:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('data', function(msg){
    io.emit('data', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Для отправки использую страницу следующую:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('data', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      socket.on('data', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

На стороне пользовательской html странице получаю сообщения след образом:

```
var socket = io.connect('***.***.***.***',{port: 3000});
    socket.on('data', function(msg){
            $('#mess').append(msg+'\n');
      });
```

Я не могу понять как с этим работать дальше, документации не хватает как воздуха. Мне нужно понять, можно ли как то настроить сервер так, чтобы можно было бы слать бинарные данные на `ip:port`, а сервер бы их считывал и открывал бы `websocket` с именем как поступило на `ip`, а после бы записывало в бд.

Клиент же в свою очередь, после авторизации на сайте получал бы имя сокета и к нему бы цеплялся и при этом не видел бы остольные...

Дайте подсказку куда хотя бы смотреть, как с этим жить и как это сделать?

Answer (score -1):

документации достаточно, вот наиболее полное, на русском, https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets .этого более чем достаточно понять, как устроено. Серверная часть - у каждого сервера своя. Раз используется браузер, то и первоначальная загрузка идет по стандартной схеме - обыкновенная HTML страница. Первоначально надо авторизоваться на сайте -логин/пароль. Это не проблема. После авторизации уже идёт подключение по ws к серверу, причём желательно привязать коннект ws к данной сессии юзера. И контролировать, чтоб новых подключений не было без соответствующей сессии авторизованного юзера. Как только такое осуществлено - можно слать и бинарные и текстовые данные. Хорошая реализация сервера позволяет обрабатывать поступающие данные как бинарные, так и текстовые. дополнительно имеется шифрованный протокол - wss. Главное организовать правильную структуру данных чтоб сервер мог их обрабатывать, а не валить в кучу.

Comment: с Websockets я замечательно умею общаться... А вот socket io я вроде понимаю и не понимаю одновременно...